# Java generic: how to declare a generic parameter as the base type of another generic parameter?

Tags: java, generics, types, type-inference

```
public class PairJ<T> {
    private T first;
    private T second;

    public PairJ(T first, T second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    public T first() {
        return this.first;
    }

    public T second() {
        return this.second;
    }

    public <R> Pair<R> replaceFirst(R newFirst) {
        return new Pair(newFirst, second());
    }
}

class Vehicle {}

class Car extends Vehicle {}

class Tank extends Vehicle {}
```

The code compiles.
But when I do this:

```
    PairJ<Car> twoCars = new PairJ(new Car(), new Car());
    Tank actuallyACar = twoCars.replaceFirst(new Tank()).second();
```

It still compiles but gives a cast exception when running, since the second element in the pair is a car, not a tank.

So I changed it to this:

```
public <R, T extends R> Pair<R> replaceFirst(R newFirst) {
    return new Pair(newFirst, second());
}
```

But this code still compiles and gives the same exception:

```
    PairJ<Car> twoCars = new PairJ(new Car(), new Car());
    Tank actuallyACar = twoCars.replaceFirst(new Tank()).second();
```

Seems like the declaration of T extends R is not working here.

How can I enforce type safety here?

More specifically, how can I make sure that java infers

```
twoCars.replaceFirst(new Tank())
```

to return a Pair of Vehicle instead of a Pair of tanks? So I would get compile time error when trying to assign its second element to a variable of the type Tank? And to reduce the chances of having run time exceptions?

Edit:

In Scala, we can do it like this:

```
class Pair[T](val first: T, val second: T) {
  def replaceFirst[R >: T](newFirst: R): Pair[R] = new Pair[R](newFirst, second)
}
```

[R >: T] makes sure that R is a base type of T, how do we do the same in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I make sure that java infers
>
> ```
> twoCars.replaceFirst(new Tank())
> ```
>
> to return a Pair of Vehicle instead of a Pair of tanks?

Provide a type argument explicitly

```
twoCars.<Vehicle>replaceFirst(new Tank())
```

You'll get a compiler error when trying to invoke

```
Tank actuallyACar = twoCars.<Vehicle>replaceFirst(new Tank()).second();
```

Comment: is it possible to tell java to infer the common base type of tank and car instead of doing it explicitly?

Comment: that works, but i am curious about why java is not acknowledging the <R, T extends R> notation.

Comment: @CuiPengFei You declare the new `T` type parameter, but you don't use it. What would even be bound to it?

Comment: oh, ok, i did not realise that. i thought that those two Ts are the same thing. then how do i refer to the T that was declared along with the class? so i could have something like this: public <R, TOfClass extends R> Pair<R> replaceFirst(R newFirst)

Comment: @CuiPengFei You already have access to the `T`. All instance methods and fields do (as long as it isn't shadowed as you previously had). The question is: how do you want to use it? It has to have some value.

Comment: so one generic parameter T is declared with the class, another R with the method, how can we express that R should be T's base type? that is how i want to use T.

Comment: @CuiPengFei I don't believe you can do this in Java. I have to review.

Comment: @CuiPengFei Yeah, it doesn't exist. [Here's an explanation why.](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#FAQ107)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56014/discussion-between-cuipengfei-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score 0):

First, pay attention to this form:

```
PairJ<Car> twoCars = new PairJ(new Car(), new Car());
```

You're getting a compiler warning in which you're doing an unchecked assignment from `PairJ` to `PairJ<Car>`.  You may run into gotchas with this later.

You can avoid this by providing the generic type, or letting Java (7.0+) infer it for you with the diamond operator.

```
PairJ<Car> twoCars = new PairJ<Car>(new Car(), new Car());
// or
PairJ<Car> twoCars = new PairJ<>(new Car(), new Car());
```

The first problem is here:

```
public <R> PairJ<R> replaceFirst(R newFirst) {
    return new PairJ(newFirst, second());
}
```

You're getting another unchecked assignment here, but this one is *worse* - you're actively changing the type of one of your parameters to something *completely* different.

The reason that this is not possible is due to the way your generic type is bound to your class.  You explicitly state that, in your constructor, you expect two arguments bound to some generic type `T`.  What you're doing *here* is binding only **one** to `R`.

If you were to "fix" the issue by doing type inference as described above, you'd get a compilation failure (which is good - you want these to fail at compile time as opposed to run time).

```
public <R> PairJ<R> replaceFirst(R newFirst) {
    return new PairJ<R>(newFirst, second());
}
```

The above fails due to it requiring parameters bound to `R, R`, not `R, T`.

The second problem is here:

```
class Vehicle {}

class Car extends Vehicle {}

class Tank extends Vehicle {}
```

Your hierarchy mandates that, while a `Car` is a `Vehicle`, and a `Tank` is a `Vehicle`, **a `Car` is not a `Tank`.**  So the `ClassCastException` is appropriate; you really *can't* cast a `Car` to a `Tank`.

This would fail since they're not convertible between the two.

```
Tank actuallyACar = twoCars.replaceFirst(new Tank()).second();
```

---

There's a solution here; if you want to keep this API, then you'll need two type parameters for your class.  This means that you can now pass in a new type `R` freely when calling `replaceFirst`.

```
class PairJ<S, T> {
    private S first;
    private T second;

    // accessors modified

    public <R> PairJ<R, T> replaceFirst(R newFirst) {
        return new PairJ<>(newFirst, second());
    }
}
```

The fun part now comes in *calling* the method.  We can construct it pretty much the same way we did before, now with two `Car` type parameters.

```
PairJ<Car, Car> twoCars = new PairJ<>(new Car(), new Car());
```

As I said earlier, a `Tank` isn't a `Car`, so this just ain't gonna work:

```
Tank actuallyACar = twoCars.replaceFirst(new Tank()).second();
```

...but this *will*:

```
Car actuallyACar = twoCars.replaceFirst(new Tank()).second();
```

The above more boiled down to the way you had your class hierarchy laid out.  It would have never worked in Java, even if you got the generics on the class right, to cast from a `Tank` to a `Car`.  While they share a common ancestor, one is not the other.

(Modern example:  you can't cast a `String` to an `Integer`, even though they're both children of `Object`.)

Comment: it was not my purpose to turn a car into a tank, all i wanted was to get a Pair<Vehicle> when replacing a car with a tank. but seems like that's not an easy task in Java.